# How do I use the data contained in a data table in all the forms in my vb.net application?

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net application that is a main MDI parent form with several child forms. In one of the child forms I have a place to insert data to create user accounts and store them in a database I created in visual studio called "UserAccounts" with a data table called "dtUsers". There is also a login form that has a place for a username and password and I want the program to search the datatable to make sure the username exists and that the password is correct. This is the code for the login form I am using the string "admin" as a placeholder for a "username" and the string password as a placeholder for a password.

```
Private Sub LoginButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginButton.Click
    If UserNameTextBox.Text = "admin" And UserPasswordTextBox.Text = "password" Then
        My.Forms.EOM_Parent.MenuStrip1.Enabled = True
        My.Forms.EOM_Parent.TreeView1.Enabled = True
        My.Forms.EOM_Parent.ToolStrip1.Enabled = True

        Close()
    Else
        MsgBox("You have entered the wrong username/password combination.")
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the code from my add user form.

```
Public Class AddUserForm

    Private myXmlFilePath = "xmlUserData.xml"

    Private Sub AddUserForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(myXmlFilePath) = True Then
            UserAccounts.ReadXml(myXmlFilePath)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CancelUserButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CancelUserButton.Click
        Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ToolStripButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton1.Click
        Me.Validate()
        DtUsersBindingSource.EndEdit()
        UserAccounts.WriteXml(myXmlFilePath)
    End Sub

End Class
```

The fields in the data table are:
UserID
FirstName
LastName
AdminUser
Password
and the UserID is the key. And the xml file is xmlUserData.xml

The only solutions I can find online are for SQL. And I know this isn't a secure way to store usernames and passwords.

Comment: `The only solutions I can find online are for SQL. And I know this isn't a secure way to store usernames and passwords.` If done correctly storing passwords in a SQL database is not more vulnerable than other methods.

Comment: I meant I know storing passwords in a database as strings isn't secure.

Answer (score -1):

Declare the DataTable as Friend in a Module:

```
Module GlobalStuff
    Friend dt As New DataTable("Foo")
End Module
```

And to reference in your login form...

```
With dt.Select("AdminUser = '" & UserNameTextBox.Text & "' And Password = '" & UserPasswordTextBox.Text & "'")
    If .Count = 1 Then
        ' Good Login
    End If
End With
```

Comment: But how would I replace this line of code with one that access the correcty database entry?  If UserNameTextBox.Text = "admin" And UserPasswordTextBox.Text = "password" Then

Comment: This is all assuming you're just prototyping mechanics and will build in proper security at some point. Personally, I'd be using Entity Framework, but that's a whole other thing.

Comment: @TM1985 how come people use FOO for examples?

Comment: @MrGadget In any case, DO NOT USE GLOBAL VARIABLES, which properties of modules aka static classes are.

Comment: @Ondřej You've got to be kidding...there are plenty of valid cases for global variables. A table of static data that's loaded once and used all over an app is such an example. There's no reason to fetch the same data over and over for many forms in the app that will need it.

Comment: @MrGadget Ever heard of passing reference, or dependency injection? Probably not. Any kind of global variable is pure hell except special cases like Singleton pattern (My.Settings or My.Resources).